FastAPI Integration Testing with Keycloak User Authentication
I'm desperately trying to write integration tests for my fastapi project for the last 5 days. For security reasons my endpoints are secured via keycloak (python-keycloak module). An example:
# custom_route.py
@router.post("/my-secured-endpoint")
def do_something_secure(data: MyData, user: KeycloakUser = Depends(validate_token)):
    return "This is secured!"

Whereas validate_token is defined from another module:
# auth.py

idp = KeycloakOpenID(
    server_url=KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL,
    realm_name=KEYCLOAK_REALM,
    client_id=KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret_key=KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET
)

oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(
    tokenUrl=idp.well_known()["token_endpoint"]
)

def validate_token(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)) -> KeycloakUser:
    decoded_token: dict = idp.decode_token(token)
    user: KeycloakUser = KeycloakUser.model_validate(decoded_token)
        
    return user


Now i want to test my-secured-endpoint using FastAPIs TestClient:

def test_custom_route():
    from routers.custom_route import router as custom_router

    app.include_router(custom_router)
    client = TestClient(app)

    data = {"some": "data"}

    response = client.post("/my-secured-endpoint", json=data)

    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.text == "This is secured!"


I'd expect the response to be 200 with text "This is secured!".
I don't want to call my IDP in the integration test. This logic is tested seperately. I just want to bypass the authentication to only execute the endpoint logic.
What i've tried:
Mocking the validate_token function with pytest.fixture

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_validate_token (monkeypatch: MonkeyPatch):
    from modules import auth
    
    class MockKeycloakUser:
        name = "test"
    
    def mock_validate_token(token):
        return Mock(return_value=MockKeycloakUser())
    
    monkeypatch.setattr(auth, "validate_token", mock_validate_token)


Mocking validate_token directly

def test_custom_route(monkeypatch):
    # ...

    monkeypatch.setattr("routers.custom_route.validate_token", lambda x: {"name": "test"})
    response = client.post("/my-secured-endpoint", json=data)

    assert response.status_code == 200


Mocking Depends()

def test_custom_route():
    # ...

    import fastapi
    monkeypatch.setattr(fastapi, "Depends", lambda x: {"name": "test"})
    response = client.post("/my-secured-endpoint", json=data)

    assert response.status_code == 200


Any help is greatly appreciated!

FastAPI has built-in support for the specific use case of overriding dependencies for testing: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/ - client.override_dependencies[validate_token] = lambda: {"name": "test"} (or a more properly named function). Use a fixture to set this up automagically for you instead of doing it inside every test. You also probably want to return a KeycloakUser and not a dictionary directly.

Thank you for the hint! I'll read the docs and try to implement it this way.
